# Is there a way to cast an abstract object to its child?

Tags: c++, inheritance, polymorphism

Let's imagine a situation where I have an abstract class named 'Base' with a virtual pure method named foo(), and 2 children (Inherited1 and Inherited2) that both implement this method in their own way. Now let's say that one of these children (Inherited1) needs another method called bar() that would make no sense to implement in Inherited2.

In my main, i Have

```
Base * randomObject = new Inherited1();
```

I can't access this method using

```
random->bar();
```

What should I do. Like I said, it would make no sense to implement it in inherited2, so I can't simply put another virtual method in Base, or should I?

Comment: `Base randomObject = new Inherited1();` --- that almost certainly doesn't compile. Are you writing C++ or Java?

Comment: sorry forgot to add pointer

Comment: @Brian He would still not be able to call a child function in Inherited1 this way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you had a variable

```
Base* randomObject = new Inherited1();
```

You could cast it down to the base class

```
Inherited1* foo = static_cast<Inherited1*>(randomObject);
foo->bar();
```

But you have to be sure that the pointer is indeed of *that* derived class otherwise `static_cast` isn't safe. There are a number of ways to do this, such as storing an `enum` in the derived classes that you can check via a `virtual` getter, or checking if the result of a `dynamic_cast` is `nullptr`, but that is slower.

Comment: Thank you, that was what I was looking for, is it bad practice to do a one time call by doing ? :

    static_cast<Inherited1*>(randomObject)->bar();

I know there has to be a design problem in my architecture, but when 10 methods are used by both children class except for one random method, I felt like I had to use polymorphism still

Comment: No that will work fine, just make sure that the cast is safe.